# StartActivity Not Firing

Tags: android

When running the code below, it throws a NullPointerException at the line "PC_Settings_Manager.getInstance().getSettings().isTTSEnabled();" The PC_Settings_Manager instance is not null since it is a singleton and it gets initialized at the application start up. The null is the Settings object. However, I count on the flow to start the welcome activity where the user is forced to go to settings screen and save the settings. At that time the settings object is not null.ALso, when I debug the debugger goes into the if statement but startActivity does not fire??? hence what am counting on does not work.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PC_Application_Constants.EHOPE_SETTINGS_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isFirstTime = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PC_Application_Constants.FIRST_TIME_USAGE_KEY, true);

    if (isFirstTime) {
        Intent pC_Welcome_Activity_Intent = new Intent(PC_LoginActivity.this, PC_Welcome_Activity.class);
        startActivity(pC_Welcome_Activity_Intent);
    }

    // Check Text To Speech Service
    boolean isTTSEnabled = PC_Settings_Manager.getInstance().getSettings().isTTSEnabled();
```

Answer (score 2):

`startActivity()` is asynchronous. It does not wait for the started activity to finish; instead your code continues to run from the next line.

If you need to wait for an activity to finish, use `startActivityForResult()` and put the follow-up code in `onActivityResult()`.